# Unable to switch to NVidia-375 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an ASUS laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M and a Skylake processor with integrated graphics running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Observations:

1. when I run `lspci` from the terminal (not with `sudo`), I get:

   ```
   ~$ lspci | grep VGA

   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake
   Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
   ```
2. I have already switched the graphics after brand new installation of Ubuntu as follows:

   [image]
3. I faced problem of freezing screen while installation so I did nouveau.modeset = 0 while booting and once booted I edited the grub file as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1122021/how-do-i-add-code-below-to-the-end-of-linux-kernel-flags-in-grub) solution i.e.

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0". Then update-grub.
   ```
4. On executing nividia-settings on terminal I get this key missing problem which I don't understand .

   [image]

Am I missing something very obvious? How do I switch to nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue after updating Ubuntu version to 17.10 and trying to set up NVIDIA drivers.

Symptoms were:

- Indication of NVIDIA driver selected in additional drivers GUI window, but lack of `nvidia-smi`
- Empty NVIDIA X Server Settings window (like on your screenshot)

Here's what I did:

- Attempted to switch a driver from terminal: `sudo apt install nvidia-375` (375 is not really critical, can be any other reasonable revision)
- Carefully read the output of the command, noticed lines: `Module build for kernel 4.13.0-16-lowlatency was skipped since the
  kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.`
- Installed missing headers `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- Tried to install driver from terminal again (maybe rebooted prior to that and after headers installation)

Maybe in your case the reason is different, but I would still suggest same overall approach:

- try running the failing command in terminal rather that from GUI (with maximum verbosity level if possible)
- carefully observe the output
- in case of any errors/warnings - make a research and try to fix them